# How to run a script from PRTG using Powershell remote to extend disk volume

Tags: powershell-remoting

I have used PRTG as monitoring solution, need to inject a PowerShell script to extend the volume on the remote machine (critical windows VM with pre-assigned disk space from the host. Unallocated disk in disk management). How do I run Get-PartitionSupportedSize in a remote PowerShell session?

My powershell script on PRTG server:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName xxx
Invoke-Command -Session $s $MaxSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter D).SizeMax
Invoke-Command -Session $s Resize-Partition -DriveLetter D -Size $Maxsize
```

Error received:
Get-PartitionSupportedSize: No MSFT_Partition objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'D'. Verify the value of the poperty and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Following example can be executed from PRTG probe

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostName -ScriptBlock {
  param ([String]$someParameter)

   Some-Command -Parameter $someParameter

} -ArgumentList $someParameter
```

In your case it would look as follows:

```
$hostName="xxx"
$driveLetter="D"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostName -ScriptBlock {
  param ([String]$driveLetter)

    $MaxSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $driveLetter).SizeMax
    Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $driveLetter -Size $Maxsize

} -ArgumentList $driveLetter
```

It makes sense to add some logging for this script on target computer in case that resizing doesn't work - for this i would use something like this inside ScriptBlock after parameter section:

```
$who = $(whoami)
Add-Content c:\temp\prtg-sensor-output.log "Starting script to resize $driveLetter as $who"
```

just a reminder - since this part is executed on target computer you need to search for that c:\temp\prtg-sensor-output.log on that xxx host